# Roslyn - replace all names by full qualified name

Tags: c#, roslyn

How can I replace all names in a block of c# code with the full qualified name? It is the intention to replace all usings with qualified names instead.
I know that it can be tricky with alias declarations, but that's not the case in our situation.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: I've tried to use a CSharpSyntaxRewriter. But the difficulty is to rewrite extension methods.

Comment: What is the difficulty with extension methods? Could you show your code and explain what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I appreciate that you need an answer (hence the bounty) but there's no enough information in this question to help you. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least some code snippets showing how you're trying to do this and what error you're getting?

Comment: I just want to have a starting point on how to do this. Which information do you need? There is no code that I can show.

Comment: How about using Resharper?

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? It is short but it is also precise and to the point. Why seasoned contributors always demand code, there are not always code snippets to every question. I don't have an answer to this question as I just started exploring Roslyn and hence came across this question. But I find how anal some people are about each and every question really unnerving. If one finds a question so below their intellect then skip the question, move on, and pick your spots. Don't make everyone's life painful.

Comment: Question upvoted because it's precise and to the point and I am curious, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can do this as a `CodeFixProvider` or a `SyntaxRewriter` implementation. In any case have a look here for a start: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/learn-roslyn-now-part-5-csharpsyntaxrewriter/

Apart from the context, you'd most probably need to handle `InvocationExpressionSyntax` nodes whose symbol is an `IMethodSymbol` with `ReducedExtension` as method kind:

```
var inv = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)node;
var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(inv).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
if (symbol.MethodKind == MethodKind.ReducedExtension)
{
  ...
}
```

And then you'll need to rewrite the `InvocationExpressionSyntax` to another one. This site helps a lot with the rewriting: https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/. You can get the full name of the method's containing type by calling `ToDisplayString()` or `ToDisplayParts()` on it.

Also, you'll need to pass the first argument to the new invocation, so you'll need to get the expression on which the invocation is called: `((MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)inv.Expression).Expression`.

You can start along these lines, and if you're stuck then you can get back to SO with a proper question.